# Binding DXexpress calendar month to button Text

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

Can someone help with this? I'm in .net Maui and I'm using the calendar inside a popup. The button to open the popup contains the month as a name. This month has to be the calendar's month. If the user changes the month, the button's text name must follow along. I don't know how to bind then.

Thanks.

Just the basic! Calling the calendar in the XML and the popup cliqued method in the code behind. I'm learning Maui.

Comment: https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/DevExpress.Maui.Editors.DXCalendar.DisplayDate

Comment: Please add the code about button and calendar popup in xaml and xaml.cs file .

Comment: Refer to Jason's link, you can get the date data after user changed the month by `SelectedDate `Property in DXCalendar.  Then you can set the date to button text after getting the selectedDate.